# bounded task flow versus unbounded taskflow in ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

Please help me in understanding the two of these task flows - Bounded and Unbounded in ADF. 
From what i read from a book, my understanding is that an unbounded taskflow can contain n number of bounded task flows. Please give me example like for what reason we can use unbounded task flows and bounded task flows.

Answer (score 5):

Taskflow is something which acts as controller for an ADF application.
It is used to define the navigation between taskflows or pages.

In ADF Taskflow is of two types.

1. **Bounded TF**
2. **Unbounded TF**

   - You can secure a Bounded TF, But unbounded TF you can't.
   - You can pass parameters and get parameters to and from a bounded taskflow, but for Unbounded TF you can't.
   - Bounded TF has only single entry point, known as default activity, but in unbounded TF multiple entry points are there.
   - You can call a bounded TF from another bounded/Unbounded TF, but for unbounded TF, you can't.
   - Bounded TF supports transaction, but unbounded TF doesn't.

See whenever you want your page not to be secured you can use unbounded TF. For example, consider a online shopping application. In the application pages like Home, About Us, Products will be in an unbounded TF. But seeing your order history, wishlist will come under bounded TF.

Answer (score 0):

**ADF bounded taskflow** is used to encapsulate a reusable portion of an application :

- Has a single entry point
- May accept input parameters
- May generate return values
- Has its own collection of activities and control flow rules
- Has its own memory scope and managed bean lifespan (a page flow scope instance)

**You typically use the unbounded task flow instead of a bounded task flow if:**

- You want to take advantage of ADF Controller features not offered by
  bounded task flows, such as bookmarkable view activities.
- The task flow will not be called by another task flow.